# How to change the axis divider line colors in Microsoft Chart Controls (column chart)

Tags: .net, charts

See the chart below. I'm building the chart programatically, so no asp.net control syntax please.

[image: bar chart example]

How do I change the grid line colours that cross horizontally and vertically behind the bars? As you can see I've worked out how to change the actual axis colours, but the grid colours remain black.

```
public ActionResult RenderChart()
{
    var chart = new Chart();
    double[] yValues = { 65.62, 75.54, 60.45, 55.73, 70.42 };
    string[] xValues = { "Michelle", "Sarah", "Aliece", "Belinda", "Amanda" };
    var series = new Series
    {
        Name = "Default",
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column,
        CustomProperties = "DrawingStyle=Cylinder"
    };
    series.Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);

    chart.BorderlineColor = Color.Silver;
    var area = new ChartArea("Test");
    area.AxisX.LineColor = Color.DarkGray;
    area.AxisY.LineColor = Color.DarkGray;

    chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);
    chart.Series.Add(series);
    series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

    series.Font = new Font(series.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    chart.Width = 400;
    chart.Height = 300;

    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        chart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Never mind, found the answer:

```
area.Axes[n].MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Whatever;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it in the HTML like this

```
 <asp:Chart ID="chartOutstandingOrders" runat="server" Width="500" Palette="Bright">

            <Series>
                <asp:Series ChartType="Line" Name="seriesBackorder">
                </asp:Series>
            </Series>

            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BorderColor="#339966">
                    <AxisX LineColor="Gray">
                        <MajorGrid LineColor="LightGray" />
                    </AxisX>
                    <AxisY LineColor="Gray">
                        <MajorGrid LineColor="LightGray" />
                    </AxisY>
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>

        </asp:Chart>
```

Answer (score 0):

For MS Chart,background grid colour can be changed by following statement.

```
myChart.ChartAreas["xSeries"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Blue;
```